# Using Page Up and Page Down on an Apple wireless keyboard

Tags: wireless-keyboard

How can I do page up/page down on an Apple wireless keyboard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
fn + up arrow   = PgUp
fn + down arrow = PgDn
```

Taken from http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1569297

Comment: Please provide the answer, don't link somewhere else.

Comment: I used up all my ability typing the phrase "apple wireless keyboard page up" in Google, so much so that all I could do was paste the first link.

Comment: normally i would agree with you Teddy, but this seems like one of those questions that could have been answered using google in about 20 seconds.

Comment: I completely agree with Teddy. I've just performed a google search for the same thing, and the top hit was this question. As soon as I spotted it was superuser, I new that I'd find the answer without any fuss.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but in Adobe Acrobat at least, I find the fn-up and fn-down seem to work just fine.  (eg hold down function key and hit up).